# C# WPF Custom Validation Rule doesn't fire

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to implement Input Validation in my WPF application (which is a plugin for Solidworks). I am using this example as a reference, and I believe I applied it correctly - https://developingfor.net/2009/10/13/using-custom-validation-rules-in-wpf/. The rule I have in my code should check if input in a Textbox is an integer or not. However, for some reason, the validation check doesn't fire. I put breakpoints in my code, and it never runs the validation function. The relevant part of my WPF:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SolidworksPlugin.MyAddInControl" 
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Solidworks_Plugin"
             xmlns:ValidationRules="clr-namespace:CustomValidationRules"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Height="600" Width="300">

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox
            x:Name="Int1TextBox"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            MinWidth="50"
            Margin="0,0,6,0">
            <Binding
                Path="Int1"
                UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                Mode="TwoWay">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <ValidationRules:IntegerValidationRule
                        Min="1"
                        Max="9999999"
                        FieldName="Int1" 
                    />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>

</UserControl>
```

And the InputValidator class that this WPF refers to for the validation rule:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace CustomValidationRules
{
    public class IntegerValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {
        private int _min = int.MinValue;
        private int _max = int.MaxValue;
        private string _fieldName = "Field";
        private string _customMessage = String.Empty;

        public int Min
        {
            get { return _min; }
            set { _min = value; }
        }

        public int Max
        {
            get { return _max; }
            set { _max = value; }
        }

        public string FieldName
        {
            get { return _fieldName; }
            set { _fieldName = value; }
        }

        public string CustomMessage
        {
            get { return _customMessage; }
            set { _customMessage = value; }
        }


        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            int num = 0;

            if (!int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out num))
                return new ValidationResult(false, String.Format("{0} must contain an integer value.", FieldName));

            if (num < Min || num > Max)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomMessage))
                    return new ValidationResult(false, CustomMessage);


                return new ValidationResult(false, String.Format("{0} must be between {1} and {2}.",
                                           FieldName, Min, Max));
            }

            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Compiler doesn't throw any errors, and when I write anything into that Textbox, the validation rule doesn't work. The `Validate()` is never reached. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you please reduce your XAML sample to the strict minimum so that we can easily try it ourselves?

Comment: I reduced it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the XAML code where you create a MyAddInControl, and the code for the associated view model?

Comment: MyAddInControl is initialized in TaskpaneHostUI class:         private void InitializeComponent()
        { this.myAddInControl1 = new SolidworksPlugin.MyAddInControl(); } }. I'm unsure what you meant by "code for the associated view model", could you be a bit more specific, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided as a sample works fine with me, I hit the breakpoint in the `ValidationRule`.

I used this `MainWindow` code to test the `Binding`:

```xml
<Window x:Class="SolidworksPlugin.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        x:Name="window"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        Topmost="True"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0 0">
    <Grid>
        <MyAddInControl></MyAddInControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and this sample code-behind to create a ViewModel:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}

public class MyViewModel {
    public int Int1 { get; set; }
}
```

The `ValidationRule` is not going to be called if the `Binding` itself does not resolve correctly, so check that your view model actually has a property named `Int1` and that the `DataContext` of your object is correctly set to that view model.

Comment: By "view model" you meant the UserControl? The textbox was called Int1Textbox, I changed it to Int1, but it still doesn't work. I didn't quite understand which object you meant.

Comment: When you write ``Path="Int1"`` in your binding in XAML, to which property `Int1` are you refering? It must be a property on a object, look how I've done it in my sample code.

Comment: I'm starting to understand, but it's still not entirely clear. I don't have MyViewModel or any similar class in my code. The user control is initialized in TaskpaneHostUI class, like this:         public TaskpaneHostUI()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        } . DataContext is never set, and I don't understand what should I set it to (everything except validation works without it)

Comment: Well you should create an object like my `MyViewModel` class and set it as `DataContext`, because the `Binding` only works with a `DataContext` set. I suggest you read some more about bindings in WPF and the MVVM pattern.

Comment: This is very complicated. I tried it like in your example, but nothing seems to work. I'll do some reading as you suggested.

Comment: Did you try setting the `DataContext` property of your control or of your window the way I did? You can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview) fr an introduction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200777/discussion-between-corentin-pane-and-justinas-rubinovas).